# Get All Rows from an ExtJS Grid Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, panel

I am updating a grid panel with rows dragged from another grid with has data coming from the database. Now I want to check the grid in which I am dropping items for avoiding duplicates. For this I want to get all the rows currently there in that grid and I searched everywhere but couldn't find the way to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourGrid.getStore().getRange()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i don't want the rows from the store cause that would be blank. i am adding the items dynamically from a different grid. so do you think this would work?

Comment: As I understand, you are dropping items from gridA to gridB. And you dont want to drop items on gridB that already exists in gridB. If this is correct, in my snippet above, I am referring to gridB. Or maybe I misunderstood your question